# base 4 to base 2 converter

Tags: c, output, memmove

This program is to convert a base 4 number to a base 2 number and it should be  done in place

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void shiftr(char num[],int i)
{
     memmove(num+i,num+i+1,strlen(num)-i);
}

char* convert4to2(char num[])
{
int i=0,len;
char ch;

    while(num[i]!='\0')
    {
        ch=num[i];
        shiftr(num,i);
        switch(ch)
        {
            case '0':num[i++]='0';
                 num[i++]='0';
                 break;

            case '1':num[i++]='0';
                 num[i++]='1';
                 break;

            case '2':num[i++]='1';
                 num[i++]='0';
                 break;

            case '3':num[i++]='1';
                 num[i++]='1';
                 break;

            default:printf("Error");
        }
    }

    num[i]='\0';
    return(num);
}



void main()
{
    char num[20];
    printf("Enter the Base 4 Number:");
    scanf("%s",&num);
    printf("The Binary Equivalent is:%s\n",convert4to2(num));   
}
```

The  output  for  an  input  of  121(base 4 number)  should  be  011001  but  its  displaying  only  01.
And for larger numbers like 12101 it displays 0100 taking the first and the last but one numeral.
What could be the problem?

Comment: This `shiftr()` function hurts, in first place.

Comment: @H2CO3 But it has to be done in place

Comment: Convert from the end of the string (first make sure the array has space for that).

Comment: I think you mistook the argument order of `void *memmove(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);`. You are shifting left, not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actively destroying your input. E.g., for the first iteration, you shift your number by one place and after that you overwrite the data at place 0 and place 1 (which contains the next 2 digits in 4-base) with your binary output for the 1st digit.

Comment: Ah! Working Thanks. The first two memmove arguments should be interchanged.

Comment: @MaheshOstwal After swapping the two arguments, have you added one to the length? (to move also the final null byte) and check if num is long enough to store after conversion.

Comment: Yup. Thanks. Added one to the length and increased the size of num.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting directly from base 4 to base 2 using characters, you could put the string through the [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) function, which converts integer string of arbitrary base to a `long`. From there it's pretty easy to print out the binary representation.

**Edit:** Example:

```
char* convert4to2(const char input[], char *output, const size_t output_length)
{
    /* First make sure the output string is long enough */
    if (output_length < (sizeof(long) * 8 + 1))  /* +1 for '\0' */
        return NULL;  /* Not enouth space */

    /* Convert from the input string to a `long` */
    long value = strtol(input, NULL, 4);  /* The last `4` is the base of the input string */

    /* Convert the number to binary */
    char *output_ptr = output;

    /* Multiply with 8 to get the number of bits */
    /* Subtract 1 because bits a numbered from zero */
    for (int bit = sizeof(long) * 8 - 1; bit >= 0; bit--)
    {
        /* `value >> bit` make the current bit the lowest bit */
        /* `& 1` to mask out all but the lowest bit */
        /* `+ '0'` to make it a proper character digit */
        *output_ptr++ = ((value >> bit) & 1) + '0';
    }

    /* Terminate the string */
    *output_ptr = '\0';

    /* Return the converted string */
    return output;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
const char num[] = "121";
char output[65];  /* `long` can be 64 bits, plus one for the string terminator */

printf("%s in base 4 is %s in base 2\n",
    num, convert4to2(num, output, sizeof(output)));
```

Comment: As I have understood do you mean to convert it into long base 10 value and then finally to binary form? If that is what you are suggesting then there's the constraint of doing it "in place". (If I have misunderstood please do reply, I am only a novice).

Comment: @MaheshOstwal `strtol` takes a string in any base (say base 4) and convert it to a native `long`. Printing out that `long` as the binary digits is very easy. Please see my example for [working example](http://ideone.com/TYKtWl).

Answer (score 0):

No need to shift upward, just work backward:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void convert4to2(char *str)
{
size_t idx;
char ch;
static char *conv[4] = {"00", "01","10", "11" };

idx = strlen(str);
str[idx*2] = 0;

while(idx--) {
    ch=str[idx];
    if (ch < '0' || ch > '3') return; /* replace by relevant error handler */
    memcpy(str+2*idx, conv[ ch - '0' ], 2 );
    }

return;
}

int main(void)
{
char quad[21] = "0123321023" ;

printf("Old:%s\n", quad);
convert4to2(quad);
printf("New:%s\n", quad);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is much more elegant.